# Max(date) not working when table are joint with find_in_set()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One has `cId` (`BigInt` ). Other table has comma separated numbers `12,34,53,23,34` (`Varchar 255`).
`news_date` is of `date` type.
I am joining these two table with `find_in_set()`. I am to join these table. 
But `max(date)` is not working in this case it's picking some random dated row.

```
SELECT
    `B`.`id` AS `cId`,
    `B`.`ccId` AS `ccId`,
    `A`.`news_date` AS `latestDate`,
    `B`.`status` AS `status`,
    `B`.`isDeleted` AS `isDeleted`
FROM
    `tradefor_mobile_db_tfs_uat`.`tfs_blog` `A`
JOIN `tradefor_mobile_db_tfs_uat`.`tfs_commodity_master` `B`
WHERE

        find_in_set(`B`.`id`, `A`.`cId`) > 0
         AND(`A`.`isDeleted` = 0) AND(`A`.`isActive` = 1) AND(`B`.`isDeleted` = 0) AND(`B`.`status` = 1)        

GROUP BY
    `B`.`id`
HAVING MAX(`A`.`news_date`)
```

It's giving same date for every id.
[image: This is the result of the above query]

Comment: Can you change your table design? Having a comma separated list is an awful thing.

Comment: @juergend Unfortunately I can't. I know that's the most efficient way out, but I can't.

Comment: It's not the join that causes you the problem (beyond what you are already aware of...). See the snswers to the duplicate question on selecting records with a group-wise maximum.